Is there a way to use fuzzy selection to narrow the choices in a wx.ComboBox (wxWidgets)
I want to populate a wx.ComboBox with a large number of items but rather than having to scroll through them all, I'd like to type a string into the ComboBox and narrow the items in the ComboBox using fuzzy search (I'm using 'thefuzz').
So I've almost got it working but there's something amiss in the plumbing. I suspect I need to capture a wider range of events so that I can implement backspace and perhaps escape, but the main problem is that I can't seem to manipulate the TextEntry in the ComboBox the way I'd like.
Has anyone already done this?
Here's my code so far:
import wx
from thefuzz import process

class ThingSelector(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, thing_descriptions):
        super(ThingSelector, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(400, 200))
        
        self.thing_descriptions = thing_descriptions

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.thing_choice = wx.ComboBox(panel, choices=self.thing_descriptions)
        self.thing_choice_block = False
        self.thing_choice_filter = ""
        self.thing_choice.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_text)

        accept_button = wx.Button(panel, label="Accept")
        accept_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.accept_button_click)

        cancel_button = wx.Button(panel, label="Cancel")
        cancel_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_cancel_button)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.thing_choice, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        buttons = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(buttons, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        buttons.Add(accept_button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        buttons.Add(cancel_button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()

    def update_choices(self, filter):
        matches = process.extractBests(filter, self.thing_descriptions, limit=10)
        self.thing_choice.SetItems([match[0] for match in matches])
        self.thing_choice.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        self.thing_choice.Popup()

    def on_text(self, event):
        # avoid recursion when I call ChangeValue
        if not self.thing_choice_block:
            self.thing_choice_block = True
            current_text = event.GetString()
            if len(current_text) == 1:
                self.thing_choice_filter += current_text
                self.update_choices(self.thing_choice_filter)
                self.thing_choice_block = False
            else:
                self.thing_choice_filter = ""
                self.thing_choice.ChangeValue(current_text)


    def accept_button_click(self, event):
        selected_thing = ""
        selection = self.thing_choice.GetSelection()
        if selection != wx.NOT_FOUND:
            selected_thing = self.thing_choice.GetString(selection)
        print(selected_thing)
        return

    def on_cancel_button(self, event):
        self.Close()

# Create list of 'thing's:
thing_descriptions = [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ]

# GUI setup
app = wx.App(False)
frame = ThingSelector(None, title="Select Thing", thing_descriptions=thing_descriptions)
app.MainLoop()


wxWidgets has autocompletion feature readily available for wxTextCtrl.

Thanks for the tip and I've got it kinda sorta working using a wx.TextCompleterSimple. Not quite there yet as the manual is a bit cryptic and I'm a bit dumb. Do you know of any tutorials or examples of this kind of thing?

please check wxPython samples/demos.

Turns out TextCompleter can't help me as it only displays 'hits' that start with the pattern. Best I can do is to have a separate TextCtrl box in which I can type the filter and bind Enter there to a function that re-populates the ComboBox. Not ideal but it works.
